# bind angularjs textarea to model after updating by controller

Tags: angularjs

In my controller I update a `textarea` with `$http`. It works as expected. But now I would like to bind `message1`, and `message2` to from model, how to do it ?

RESULT:

```
This is {{message1}} in 1st line
This is {{message2}} in last line
```

in CONTROLLER:

```
$scope.myTextArea = response.data;
```

in HTML:

```
<form name="myform">
  <p><input type="text" ng-model="message1"/>Message1</p>
  <p><input type="text" ng-model="message2"/>Message2</p>
</form>
<p>
  <textarea type="text" id="textarea" model="myTextArea" cols="80" rows="10" >
    {{myTextArea}}
  </textarea>
</p>
```

Comment: Have you wrapped your "RESULT" within the ```ng-controller```?

Comment: not sure what wrapping do you mean,  console.log(response.data) and textarea part of html output give the same RESULT. Maybe I should use jquery to just update id="textarea" instead. I mean just top get rid of model "myTextArea"

Answer (score 1):

Wrapping means that you need to place your code inside the built-in `ng-controller` directive in order to achieve anything.

Here is also a working copy at [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/TohGPljUuK6ct094g6uh?p=preview).

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <form name="myform" ng-controller="myController">

          <!-- Place your "RESULT" inside the controller (myController) scope -->
          This is {{message1}} in 1st line <br />
          This is {{message2}} in last line

          <p><input type="text" ng-model="message1"/>Message1</p>
          <p><input type="text" ng-model="message2"/>Message2</p>
    </form>
    <p>
          <textarea type="text" id="textarea" model="myTextArea" cols="80" rows="10" >
            {{myTextArea}}
          </textarea>
    </p>
</body>
```

Comment: appreciate, but textarea is empty. What I am looking for is textarea to have text assigned in controller and then being able to type message1 and message2 in textarea This is {{message1}} in 1st line This is {{message2}} in last line

Comment: @irom I am not sure I quite understand what you mean, could you please better clarify?

Answer (score 1):

You mean that you want to put both messages to textarea? Then you need to use watch

```
$scope.$watchGroup(['message1', 'message2], function(newValues, oldValues, scope) {
    $scope.myTextArea = 
    'This is '+message1+' in 1st line\r\n'+
    'This is '+message2+' in last line'
});
```